Regex modification in SQL
when I try out this SQL in a db2 environment, it gives me correctly the result I want, the digits of the string
select 
CAST
(
  REGEXP_REPLACE(Word, '[^0-9]', '') AS INTEGER
) AS NUMBER_PART
from
(
  values
  (1, 'this, 1234, that')
, (2, 'this 6753')
, (3, 'this 8765 that')
, (4, 'that 98565')
, (5, '123 this')
) t(id, word)

I would like to exptend this, however, so that a sith row can be used:
(6, '404-354156,390575454,Wertpapierdepot,8')

currently, this would give an overflow error, as there are several digits in this sixth. I would like it to ignore all numbers with a hyphen. So "X-XX" numbers should be omitted. Plus I would like all one digit numbers to be ignores, so that I also get 390575454 when I add the sith row.
Is that possible with one SQL?

Just add - to the end of your character set. [^0-9-]

sorry, I don't understand..What would the regex statement look like?

@CAustin 's comment does not actually remove numbers with hyphens, it adds the hyphen to the retained characters list which will trigger a different error upon converting to INT.

DB2
SELECT 
    CAST(
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(
            REGEXP_REPLACE(Word, '(?<![0-9])[0-9](?![0-9])', ''), -- Remove all standalone single digits (0-9)
            '[0-9]+'
        ) AS INTEGER
    ) AS NUMBER_PART,
    TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Word, '\\b[0-9]\\b', ''), '[0-9]', '')) AS TEXT_PART -- Remove digits to get text part
FROM
    (
        VALUES
            (1, 'this, 1234, that'),                -- Expect: 1234
            (2, 'this 6753'),                       -- Expect: 6753
            (3, 'this 8765 that'),                  -- Expect: 8765
            (4, 'that 98565'),                      -- Expect: 98565
            (5, '123 this'),                        -- Expect: 123
            (6, '390575454,Wertpapierdepot,8'),    -- Expect: 390575454
            (7, '2,390575454,Wertpapierdepot,4,1'), -- Expect: 390575454
            (8, 'just 8 and some text 123'),        -- Expect: 123 
            (9, 'numbers like 3, 4, and 5')         -- Expect: NULL (no digits left)
    ) AS t(id, Word);


This is AI generated code.

fantastic! Thanks

Try Regexp_Replace(word, '(\d+-)+\d+|(\d{2,})|\D+', '$2').
This one finds 3 different patterns, separated by the vertical bar, but it only replaces data when the middle one is scanned.  The first part eliminates all numbers with embedded hyphens, the second scans all numeric strings of length > 1 (and retains them), and the last scans everything else (so it will also be discarded).
Here is your example using REGEX101,


instead of removing the unwanted characters it may be easier to write a regex to keep the wanted characters. in this case:

keep the group of 2 or more digits surrounded by word boundary
select 
CAST
(
  REGEXP_REPLACE(word, '^.*\b([0-9]{2,})\b.*$', '$1') AS INTEGER
) AS NUMBER_PART
from
(
  values
  (1, 'this, 1234, that')
, (2, 'this 6753')
, (3, 'this 8765 that')
, (4, 'that 98565')
, (5, '123 this')
, (6, '404-354156,390575454,Wertpapierdepot,8')
, (7, '123-4567') -- this use case doesn't work 
) t(id, word)



the use case where you have X-YY number but no other number it will match YY
